# kivy buildozer deploy error

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

I am running "buildozer android deploy"  command to install my kivy app in my samsung tablet. (Ubuntu 32 bit)
It work all the time but since yesterday it generate the error below:
I have never edited any of the adb file, thus I don't understand why Syntax error: ")" unexpected.
I try un-install and re-install buildozer but it couldn't help.

### anyone have any idea how can I fix it?

```
# Distribution already compiled, pass.
# Run '/home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/platform-tools/adb devices'
# Cwd None
/home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/platform-tools/adb: 1: /home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/platform-tools/adb:   **Syntax error: ")" unexpected
# Command failed: /home/user/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/platform-tools/adb devices****
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2**
```

Comment: try to update you Android SDK...

Comment: I would try to use the sdk-21 - it worked for me

Comment: I tried to update my android SDK by installing  libgl1-mesa-dev, openjdk-7-jdk, download android sdk 24.4.1. The same error appear.